# Selenium PageFactory - Check if on correct page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Summary**

With the PageFactory, how do I ensure the correct page has been passed to the appropriate page object? For example making sure that a real login page is being passed to an instance of the LoginPage object.

**Details**

I notice on the [PageObjects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) documentation that they explain how, in the constructor, that you can check to see if you are on the right page. For example

```
    // Check that we're on the right page.
    if (!"Login".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
        // Alternatively, we could navigate to the login page, perhaps logging out first
        throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the login page");
    }
```

However, when reading the [PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) docs, they don't explain how to check if the correct page has been passed in. They just go ahead and attempt to run the test. How can I best check this when using PageFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put an assertion in your constructor that checks the URL is valid e.g.

```
MyPage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

    assert wait.until(currentURIIs(new URI("http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.html")));
}
```

The above is using the following expected condition:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> currentURIIs(final URI pageURI) {
    new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            new URI(driver.currentUrl) == pageURI;
        }
    }
}
```

You could of course search for an element you know is on the page, or any other uniquely identifying feature.  Checking the current page URI is one possible option, there are many other things you could check to ensure you are on the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

The test should call `page.get()`.  Then the get function will call `isLoaded()`.  If `page.isLoaded()` doesn't throw an exception, then it will assume that its loaded, and return.

Otherwise, it will call `page.load()`, and then `page.isLoaded()` again. (to make sure that its actually loaded).

So each of your classes that extend `LoadablePageComponent` need to have a `isLoaded()` and `load()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The problem is that if the wrong page is used to create the, for example, instance of LoginPage then it may all die with NoSuchElementException. This all happens before load() and isLoaded() is called. How can I properly handle a completely wrong page sent to a PageFactory created object? E.g. a blank page with nothing to match on.

Comment: By passing in the page, do you mean passing in a Page object to another page?  If so, I've never seen anything like that.  However, when I create an instance of each of my pages, I pass in a driver, and then in my load() function I call driver.get() with the url to go to to get to the page.

Comment: My confusion is that, in a PageFactory created object there is no driver. In a PageObject the driver is given to the constructor. How do you use the driver from within a PageFactory created object? Only the automagically created WebElement is usable.

Comment: Have each Page have a private instance of the driver, that is assigned in the constructor (or, have all of your pages extend a class that stores a protected instance of the driver in it's constructor)